# best way to keep array's in code

Tags: objective-c

Dear all.
I need to keep some temporary information in code. When i access to it, i make instant copy of my class, receive result as MutableArray, but i have to using this array in other method's of code. 
I don't like to make instant copy of my class again, bcs this take memory and processor time, but i have to using rest of array in other methods.
Currently i keep it in array controller, but i like to find other better way.
In some reasons i don't like to send pointer to this MutableArray as method's parameter.
ProjectArrays.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface ProjectArrays : NSObject {
NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;    
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;
+(ProjectArrays *)sharedProjectArrays;

@end
```

ProjectArrays.m:

```
#import "ProjectArrays.h"
#import "SynthesizeSingleton.h"

@implementation ProjectArrays

SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(ProjectArrays)

@synthesize myMutableArray;

- (void)dealloc {
// Clean-up code here.
[myMutableArray release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
[[ProjectArrays sharedProjectArrays].myMutableArray addObject:@"Test"];

NSLog (@"This is test first point:%@",[[ProjectArrays sharedProjectArrays].myMutableArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

2010-11-21 19:26:18.636 snow[14523:a0f] This is test first point:(null)

looks like code can't care objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using singleton pattern. Create some singleton class and keep there environmental variables.

Here is useful header file: http://snipplr.com/view/32737/synthesizesingleton-definition-header/

It will help you to create singletons promptly.

**EDITED:**

Here is a singleton you'd like to use

```
//YourSingletonClassName.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface YourSingletonClassName : NSObject {
  NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;

+ (YourSingletonClassName *)sharedYourSingletonClassName;

@end


//YourSingletonClassName.m
#import "YourSingletonClassName.h"
#import "SynthesizeSingleton.h"

@implementation YourSingletonClassName

SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(YourSingletonClassName)

@synthesize myMutableArray;

- (id) init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self != nil) {
     self.myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray new];
  }
  return self;
}


- (void) dealloc {
  [myMutableArray release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

You can call `YourSingletonClassName` anywhere by `[YourSingletonClassName sharedYourSingletonClassName];`,  you shouldn't alloc/init it, e.g:

```
[[YourSingletonClassName sharedYourSingletonClassName].myMutableArray addObject:@"some_object_to_add"];
```

Please google for singleton pattern and dig through obj c conceptions.

Comment: Can u explain little bit more for that? I'm newbie in objective-c.

Comment: You should create a singleton class that contains a `NSMutableArray *myMutableArray` property. To create such a class you should include there a header file from the link I've provided, then call `SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(YourSingletonClassName);` inside its `@implementation` section and then you can call `[YourSingletonClassName sharedYourSingletonClassName].myMutableArray` in any place of your project (don't forget to include `YourSingletonClassName.h` as soon as you want to use your singleton). Is it a bit clearer now?

Comment: where i can declare myMutableArray in this header file?

Comment: You should use this header file to call `SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(YourSingletonClassName);` in your singleton `YourSingletonClassName.m` file in `@implementation` section. Your `myMutableArray` should be placed in YourSingletonClassName class.

Comment: there is some places in YourSingletonClassName to declare myMutableArray. Can u show a real example?

Comment: Thank u for explanation. Just last question - how i can update mutable array from code? Can u place example?

Comment: `[[YourSingletonClassName sharedYourSingletonClassName].myMutableArray addObject:@"some_object_to_add"];`

Comment: you should initialize your array to operate with it. see edits

Comment: i was read some critic for using singleton  patterns in design. Can u comment?

Comment: sorry, this is another topic to discuss